# Finding minimum on graph for given domain

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

So I want to find what is the minimum value of a graph on a certain domain. For example, for $y=x^2+1$ between $x=-3$ and $2$, the minimum value is at 1 at x=0. I think I know how to find minimums (first derivative, then second derivative...I think?) but I am unsure of how to find that on a certain part of the domain rather than the entire domain.

Comment: You can look for critical points using derivatives. But for closed intervals you have to also check the values on the boundaries of the interval.

Answer (score 1):

To make it complete:

For a differentiable function the maxima (minima) in an interval $[a,b]$ occur at the points where $y'=0$ or at $a$ and $b$. To decide where, you have to calculate the function values at all these points and to compare them. The second derivative test at a point with $y'=0$ says only if there is a *local* minimum or maximum there, but not that the value there is the minimum or maximum for the whole interval.

So for a maximum, find all points with $y'=0$ and $y''\leq 0$. Compare the values there and the values at the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the minimum is $x = 0$. You can find this by finding the first derivative and setting it to $0$. This has to do with the first derivative showing if a function is going up or down for any $x$. For all $y = 2x$, $y=0$ => $x=0$.

Comment: Whoops, I made a mistake in my description. What about now? How would I find the minimum on a part of the domain rather than the entire domain?

Comment: So what you can do, is notice that f'(x) = 0 for any maximum or minimum. So in any part of a domain, if f'(x)!=0, you know one of the ends will be a max or min.

Comment: In this example, f'(x)=0 for x=0, so x=0 is a maximum or minimum. Since f(-3) = 10 and f(2)=5, you know f(0)=1 is the lowest point.

Comment: please mark correct if I answered your question